# DropDownList value is empty when postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

On the `Page_Load` event, I loaded and bound data from db to `DropDownList`.

Before beginning the data loading from db, I added default value as:

```
ddlDrop.Items.Add(new ListItem("All","All"));
ddlDrop.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

in loop:

```
ddldrop.Items.Add(new ListItem());
```

and it's working perfect.

The problems is when I change `SelectedIndex`, it's post-back but the selected `DropDownList` value is empty yet.

`ddlDrop.SelectedItem.Value`  -> returns empty instead the selected value.

Comment: are you using update panel?

Comment: @AhsanAzizAbbasi nope , im not using update the dropdown bind on page load

Comment: While binding dropdown you checked IsPostBack property ??

Comment: @JaydipJ yes i was checked the isPostback .

Comment: are you binding dropdown lis inside if(!page.ispostback){} ..?

Comment: well u have 2 choices for this....first again bind the list on selected index changed event of drop down.....or put drop down tag in update panel

Comment: @AhsanAzizAbbasi you meant create am event on selected index change ? ddlSelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddl_SelectedIndexChanged); -> is it something like this ??

Comment: yes, or any post back event that you are using like button event.....I wrote a code that stable your view on post back

Comment: @AhsanAzizAbbasi thanks bro .. upvoted

Comment: but rebinding on index changed will refresh list every time and you won't select any item...

Comment: give it a try may be it solve your problem

Comment: @AhsanAzizAbbasi noted bro .. thanks again (Y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are adding the below code in pageload.

```
 ddlDrop.Items.Add(new ListItem("All","All"));
 ddlDrop.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

It will execute everytime postback happens. hence you are fist setting the slected index 0 on every postback and you selection is lost. just put the code in a if condition

```
  if(!IspostBack)// will prevent from executing on every postback
  {
       ddlDrop.Items.Add(new ListItem("All","All"));
       ddlDrop.SelectedIndex = 0;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
here is the sample    


 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <triggers>
                  <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddldropdown" />
             </triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>

     <asp:dropbdown ID="ddldropdown" etc...../>

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

And there could be another issue cause this problem is `enableviewstate` property ..
if this values set to false and we retrieve specific dropdownlist listitems from db on post back the state may lost since the property value as false.

the common mistake when trigger this problem could be manually we set the `enableviewstate` as false in backend while in view as true , so double check this property.

Answer (score 0):

First set `AppendDataBoundItems="true"` on your dropdown

At beginning the data loading from db, default value you should change to

```
ddlDrop.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All", "All"));
```

it will add item at Index 0. that will be your default selection. then you can change the SelectedIndex as per your need and it will keep that value instead of 0.